# The domain is inserted right but FB login still gives a "the given url is not allowed by the application configuration"

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, authentication, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I'm making a facebook login for a client. But i keep getting the error:

> the given url is not allowed by the application configuration

This is not new to me and I know what the error means and how to correct it. But this time i'm really puzzled, as I have tried every possible solution and still no result.

I'm using the newest `Facebook PHP SDK (v.3.2.2)` and integrated it into a `codeigniter (v.2.0)` project i received from my client. I have tried every possible website url. With and without http, with and without www and with and without slashes.

Please write if you need more information.

```
DOCUMENTATION :
The facebook settings right now :
App name: myDomain.com
App Namespace : myDomain.com
Sandbox Mode : off
Allowed domains : myDomain.com (Also tried www.myDomain.com just to test)
Website with Facebook Login : http:// www.myDomain.com/
```

THE HTTP REQUEST (I highlighted the most important) :

```
GET /dialog/oauth?client_id=416398375038503&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myDomain.com%2F&state=c7fcaa638bb00e28177b2551ab285199&scope=email HTTP/1.1
Host: www.facebook.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36
Referer: **http://www.myDomain.com/**
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: da-DK,da;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: locale=da_DK; datr=c352UWXk3ZNnDRb9vF_flCKf; lu=ThIiiPnfHJO6URgttq6n991g; p=30; presence=EM371808349EuserFA21015531322A2EstateFDsb2F1371646911100Et2F_5b_5dElm2FnullEuct2F1371756338BEtrFnullEtwF2809378943EatF1371808247422EwmlFDfolderFA2inboxA2Ethread_5fidFA2user_3a1275290355A2CG371808349901CEchFDp_5f1015531322F9CC; sub=8192; act=1371810189642%2F3; c_user=1015531322; csm=2; fr=0Q2dUDn4VqDw2NwPO.AWUeSLjGpJH-4uKuONHiGbL-jYE.BRdn55.S8.AWVTnqQG; s=Aa7pqsZ0XxblFusE.BRwH3a; xs=1%3A7IUHTcAXzyAQdg%3A2%3A1371569626; wd=1363x712

Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
client_id:416398375038503
redirect_uri: **http://www.myDomain.com/**
state:c7fcaa638bb00e28177b2551ab285199
scope:email
```

Answer (score -2):

Try once by removing the Allowed domains setting